# jquery scrolltotop not working in browsers except chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

i have created a function for scroll to top in jquery. but it is not working in browsers except chrome. please help.

style part:

```
  <style>
  #gototop {
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom:100px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  z-index:90000000;
  }
  </style>
```

Html part:

```
<div id="gototop"><img src="gototop.png"></div>
```

script part:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){

    var pstatic = $(window).width()/4;

    $('#gototop').fadeOut(05);

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pcurrent = $(this).scrollTop();
        (pcurrent <= pstatic) ? $('#gototop').fadeOut(500) : $('#gototop').fadeIn(500);
    })

    $("#gototop").on("click",function(){
            $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000, 'swing');
    });

})();
</script>
```

Comment: `$('html,body').animate(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the animate function on the `body` and the `html` tag to make sure it works in all browsers.

```
$("#gototop").on("click",function(){
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000, 'swing');
});
```